# wcf OperationContextScope dispose

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I have a c# app that calls a wcf serivce using OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(i.InnerChannel);

I need to leave the connections open so I cannot dispose the OperationContextScope with the Using statement.  However when looking at the memory profiler I am seeing hundreds of OperationContextScope's. I need to dispose the scope but when I call .Dispose() I get an error saying its out of order.  I have no idea why I cannot dispose the scope.

Does anyone know how to correctly dispose OperationContextScope ? Below is part of my code.

```
                BasicHttpBinding wsbinding = null;                  
                 OperationContextScope scope  = null;

                    wsbinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
                    wsbinding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
                    wsbinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
                    wsbinding.Name = "BasicHttpBinding_Iretail";



                i = new IretailClient(wsbinding, new EndpointAddress(commonStuff.EndpointAddress));

                scope = new OperationContextScope(i.InnerChannel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontextscope.aspx:

> When an OperationContextScope is created, the current OperationContext
>   is stored and the new OperationContext becomes the one returned by the
>   Current property. When the OperationContextScope is disposed, the
>   original OperationContext is restored.

Clearly, they must be disposed in the reverse order they were created.

```
scope.Dispose();
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot use the "Using statement" I need to know how to do dispose without using "Using"

Comment: when I call Scope.Dispose() I get an error saying it's disposed out of order :/

Comment: ? you call Dispose()... What else do you need to know?

Comment: when I call .Dispose() .net throws an exception for "Dispose is out of order" whatever that means.  I'll keep playing with the dispose

Comment: please show some simple test code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I changed it from a class to a static class and now it works. Must of been disposed before I tired to dispose it. thanks